# Export mongodb data into excel using button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mongodb, meteor

In my meteor app i have a collection name vehicle , and i want to get a excel file of that collection

```
    {
    "id": "01",
    "make": "toyota",
    "year": [
        2005,
        2006,
        2007,
        2008,
        2009,
        2010
    ],
    "model": "fortuner",
    "type": "a"
} {

    "id": "02",
    "make": "toyota",
    "year": [
        2005,
        2006,
        2007,
        2008,
        2009,
        2010
    ],
    "model": "land cruiser 200",
    "type": "b"
} {
    "id": "03",
    "make": "toyota",
    "year": [
        2005,
        2006,
        2007,
        2008,
        2009,
        2010
    ],
    "model": "land cruiser 200",
    "type": "e"
}
```

i want to get a excel file when i click a button

ID   Make     Year        Model    Make

01   toyota   2005-2010   a        xxxx

02   xxx      xxxx        xxx      xxxxxx

how can i do this in meteor ???

Answer (score 2):

On your submit click you have to execute this query

```
mongoexport --db <<your database name>> --collection vehicle --type=csv --fields  id,Make,year,Model
```

Here are two `npm` package that can be used

https://www.npmjs.com/package/datapumps

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-to-csv

Comment: any npm package to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in a project. 
I have use *exceljs* that is an npm library that permits to create excel file.
I have created a server side route to call when user click download button.

```
Router.route('/export/cart', { where: 'server' }).post(function () {
   var body = this.request.body;
   var cart = Cart.findOne({_id: body.cartId});
   var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: body.userId});

   var Excel = Meteor.npmRequire('exceljs');
   var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
   var attachmentFilename = cart.title+" "+moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY')+".xlsx";
   this.response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type':"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + attachmentFilename
    });

    /* your logic to fill excel file check exceljs for doc*/

    /*then write responde */
    workbook.xlsx.write(this.response);
});
```

This app it's been developed before Meteor 1.3 so it use NpmRequire, but this cose it's only to get the idea of how to do that.